# Get the first element of an array that is defined and not null

Tags: php, variable-assignment

I would like to assign a variable that is the first not null element from another set of variables. Much like the conditional assignment in ruby `||=`. For example:

```
<?php
$result = null;
$possibleValue1 = null;
// $possibleValue2 not defined
$possibleValue3 = 'value3';

if (isset($possibleValue1) && !is_null($possibleValue1)) {
    $result = $possibleValue1;
} else if (isset($possibleValue2) && !is_null($possibleValue2)) {
  $result = $possibleValue2;
} else if (isset($possibleValue3) && !is_null($possibleValue3)) {
  $result = $possibleValue3;
}
```

Is there a way to do this simply in php, like so (if possible, I would like to avoid creating a function and just use functions from the php library):

```
$result = firstNotNull(array($possibleValue1, $possibleValue2, $possibleValue3));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the shortest way is:

```
 $result = current(array_filter(array($possibleValue1, $possibleValue2, $possibleValue3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If all `$possibleValues` are definitely set:

```
$possibleValues = array($possibleValue1, $possibleValue2, ...);
```

If they may not be set:

```
$possibleValues = compact('possibleValue1', 'possibleValue2', ...);
```

Then:

```
$result = reset(array_filter($possibleValues, function ($i) { return $i !== null; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not know about such a function in PHP but why not creating Your own?

```
function getFirstNotNullValue($values = array()) {
    foreach($values as $val)
        if($val) return $val;
    return false;
}
```